# Hard time adding UIView with to a UIViewController as a subview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I basically want to use the PlacardView.m and PlacardView.h from the Apple's MoveMe example, by adding it as a subview on my main BlowViewController

PlacardView.m

```
#import "PlacardView.h"

@implementation PlacardView

@synthesize placardImage;



- (id)init {
    // Retrieve the image for the view and determine its size
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placard.png"];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    // Set self's frame to encompass the image
    self = [self initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.opaque = NO;
        placardImage = image;
        }
    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [placardImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}





@end
```

PlacardView.h

```
@interface PlacardView : UIView {
    UIImage *placardImage;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *placardImage;

// Initializer for this object
- (id)init;

@end
```

This is my MicBlowViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>

@class PlacardView;

@interface MicBlowViewController : UIViewController {
    AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
    NSTimer *levelTimer;
    double lowPassResults;

    PlacardView *placardView;
}


@property(nonatomic, retain) PlacardView *placardView;
- (void)setUpPlacardView;
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer;

@end
```

This is the partial MicBlowViewController.m .. there is a function viewDidLoad but that has nothing to do with the views.. its simply a timer for audio recording so I am not pasting that

```
#import "MicBlowViewController.h"
#import "PlacardView.h"

@implementation MicBlowViewController

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            [self setUpPlacardView];
        }
        return self;
    }


    - (void)setUpPlacardView {
        // Create the placard view -- its init method calculates its frame based on its image
        PlacardView *aPlacardView = [[PlacardView alloc] init];
        self.placardView = aPlacardView;
        [aPlacardView release];
        placardView.center = self.center;
        [self addSubview:placardView];
    }
```

The error I get is  "Property 'center' not found on object of type "MicBlowViewController *""

Please help.

Comment: The `viewDidLoad` method name is a little confusing at first because a `UIViewController` subclass is *not* a view, it's a View Controller. Views have `center`s and `frame`s and all sorts of other view related things; View Controllers don't - they have Views.

Comment: The viewDidLoad was a function already existing when I created the view based application..

Comment: I know. What I meant was, viewDidLoad` is a method in `UIViewController`, not `UIView`

Comment: Exactly, I meant the MicBlowViewController has a viewDidLoad function which I haven't pasted since that seems irrelevant.. However, I can't still get the image to display.. Any idea?

Comment: This line:   [self addSubview:placardView];  should be :   [self.view addSubview:placardView];  Sine self is your view controller called MicBlowViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ayush, your code leaves me somewhat puzzled.

The code for your controller seems to have several problems.

A UIViewController does not have an `initWithFrame` method, but rather a standard `init`, or an `initWithNibName:bundle:` method if using an Interface Builder file.

I see you have copied and pasted code from Apple's MoveMe example, however, bear in mind that the `MoveMeView` from which you have copied the code into your controller is actually a **UIView** and not a **UIViewController**.

Try this:

```
#import "MicBlowViewController.h"
#import "PlacardView.h"

@implementation MicBlowViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [self setUpPlacardView];

        // Additonal code with your timer etc
    }


    - (void)setUpPlacardView {
        // Create the placard view -- its init method calculates its frame based on its image
        PlacardView *aPlacardView = [[PlacardView alloc] init];
        self.placardView = aPlacardView;
        [aPlacardView release];
        [self.view addSubview:placardView];
        self.placardView.center = self.view.center;
    }
```

You will probably also need to implement the `loadView` method of your `MicBlowViewController`.

You may want to check out [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html), as well as [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks you so much Mutix. I had tried that.. the code gives me an error at self.placardView = aPlacardView "Program received signal SIGABRT"
How do I implement the loadView method? 
PS : I am TOTALLY new to iOS development.

Comment: Well you need to @synthesize your placardView property in your implementation (.m) But please listen to Mutix and read those guides: it's much easier to start from a point where everything works properly (but simply) than try to muddle through fixing bits and pieces.

Comment: Thanks again Tim! I did read these.. and I understood Apple's MoveMe example too.. However, I cannot understand how I can do what Apple did with two views.. using 1 view and 1 view controller...
I synthesized the property but I still can't get the image to display.. I guess is something to do with the .xib file 
while I try to read, any other suggestion/help will be thoroughly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
placardView.center = self.center;
```

to this:

```
placardView.center = self.view.center;
```

`self` is the UIViewController, but you want the center of its view.

Comment: Thanks! The errors are gone but I still don't get the image.. do I need to do something in the viewDidLoad function?

Answer (score 1):

Had same problems. Nearly all sample code uses view controllers and views that were created separately (the way that Xcode used to work I guess). Xcode now creates ViewController together with a view as a property (the view you see on the GUI). The kicker is that you cannot access the code for this view (afaict... I asked and got told to read the manual). So how can you get the sample code (which is in a view) into this view when you can't see it's code?

Two ways I have found:

1. Create new view that is the same as code in sample views. Then, click on the Storyboard, in GUI you are looking at the ViewController's default view. In the right hand pane, click on the identity inspector (meaningless shape third from left). You will see Class:UIView. Replace the word UIView with the name of the view that you created. The ViewController will now load your view. The other gotcha is that when you create the view it gets method initWithFrame which says it runs init code. It does not. You need to create initWithCoder (google this) and put your init code in here.
2. The other option (probably the correct way) is to use the ViewController code to add your view (with the sample code) as a subview of the default view e.g. in ViewController.m

   `Bus *newBus = [[Bus alloc] init];`

   `[self.view addSubview:newBus];`

   i.e. self is the ViewController and view is its default view i.e. a property of ViewController

Comment: Wow! Thanks. That makes things a lot more clear. Also, could you tell me what is the best way to work with multiple views (switching views) Navigation Controller, programmatically adding a view and removing it or multiple view controllers and nib files?